# how to debug a div that shows and hides almost instantly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, debugging

On my website, I have a lot of code, many js vendors, etc.

On one specific page, I have king of a right sidebar that pops out for less than half a second, never enough for me to click on it and try to debug this weird thing (I'm thinking of putting a display none on its class).

I've tried to go through the dom and place dom breakpoints in my chrome browser but it's not doing nothing.

Does someone know how I could debug something like this ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Use "inspect element" to detect the sidebar  and then navigate to the class or id which has the display:none; property. Then you can click it on or off in the developer toolbar...

Comment: how can I detect something that hides instantly ?

Comment: Detect anything in that page which is near the sidebar.. Then you will see the sidebar code in the developer toolbar area.. usually it should have an id or class of sidebar..